# What do you call a pronoun without an antecedent?

Tags: word-request

Let's say someone says "It started." out of nowhere. "It" doesn't have an antecedent. How would you qualify such a pronoun? I am thinking "dangling pronoun", but the term is rarely ever used, so I am thinking there might be a more formal word or term for it.

Comment: Note that regardless of what you call it, that sentence is meaningless without more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*it* without an antecedent is a *dummy pronoun*: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun

However, in “It started”, as Jason Bassford points out, we don’t know what *it* refers to. This is probably not a dummy pronoun. *Something* started. This *it* is different from the *it* in (for example) “it rained”, where *it* definitely has no antecedent.